# CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID is null in contacts db

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I tought that it's not possible that Phone.CONTACT_ID column is null when retrieving contacts from Phone.CONTENT_URI. However I've received many crash reports from my users like this one:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: activity.contentResolver…taKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID) must not be null
```

Probably because I'm sorting sql results by CONTACT_ID, here's the sample code

```
activity.contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                arrayOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_PRIMARY,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TIMES_CONTACTED,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL),
                "${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER} = ?" +
                        " AND ${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER} IS NOT NULL" +
                        " AND ${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID} IS NOT NULL",
                arrayOf("1"),
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)
```

The exception is thrown from the first line of the snippet I provided. And now I've got two questions:

1) Why I see this error altought I have specified `${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID} IS NOT NULL` in my sql query?

2) In which situation Phone.CONTACT_ID is null?

Answer (score 0):

try changing your sort parameter to

```
val sortOrder = "${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID} ASC"
```

also `CONTACT_ID` should never be null, so i would remove the

```
AND ${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID} IS NOT NULL
```

part.

Comment: But how adding `"${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID} ASC"` can change the query? "ASC" is a default sort order. 

_also CONTACT_ID should never be null_
But it looks like it is null, or do you think the error message is missleading?